# 12TB storage, can someone help me? :)

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, raid, lvm, mdadm

I have thought about making a RAID 5 with 4 hard drives, 4TB each. There are files with few KB and other files with some GB. I want it to be as stable as possible. This will not be mounted as / or /home or others. I want to use it in Debian, Ubuntu and Fedora.

1. What filesystem do you recommend - ext4, xfs, btfrs, zfs...

   i. If it was ext4, I can reduce the reserved space safely (5%)? Until what percentage can I reduce it safely?
2. Which method is recommended to make the software RAID mdadm, (lvm) ... (I don't intend to do dynamic partitions)?
3. Have Ubuntu RAID auto-detected?
4. How can I get Ubuntu to send me an email, when some disk fails?

Comment: Look very closely at a zfs solution with a smallish (128-256GiB) ssd for a scratch drive. Just be warned..ZFS loves ram but can be very fast.

Comment: Usually one question per "question".

Answer (score 0):

suggestions:
- use ext3 or ext4. I just go with defaults, sorry.

- I use mdadm. it works, is relatively easy to configure, and there's lots of support info out there found through google. There's a book or two also - O'Reilly - "Managing RAID on Linux" has useful info.
- I haven't succeeded in getting Ubuntu to auto mount arrays, but I probably gave up too easily. I just mount the arrays when I boot. Also gives me a chance to e2fsck the arrays while they're not mounted. That's important, especially in RAID 5. Also chance to check array status.

Answer (score 0):

couple more pointers.

1. if you use mdadm to manage the raid array, when you install mdadm it asks questions to configure email settings for warning messages. So, you can set it up to send an email to specified address when problem occurs. I'll assume you can handle email server setup.
2. RAID 5 is problematic with large drives (anything over 1TB). RAID 5 was invented when drives were measured in dozens of megabytes. The problem is, the slightest hiccup throws the drive off the array, forcing it to run in degraded mode. People with large arrays (a lot of drives) increasingly find that the array can't be rebuilt, because the rebuild process examines every sector of every drive, and with large drives, the likelihood of being able to do that without encountering an error is not high - so, the rebuild fails. 4TB drives should be a real challenge. You might consider just going with RAID 0. Yes, you lose fault tolerance, but, you should be backing it up anyway, RAID 5 is NOT a substitute for backup!
3. That is why RAID 6 was invented - RAID 6 works like 5, except there are two spares instead of one. So, if you lose one drive, you don't go into degraded mode. Obviously this affects storage capacity accordingly. But, assuming you eventually need to rebuild the array, it takes even longer.
4. Assuming you still want to do RAID 5, buy good disk drives. Western Digital "enterprise" level drives are a reasonable choice. They're a little more expensive than every day ones, but they are better for RAID5. Shop carefully. No cheapies.
5. If you encounter an error, and the array goes into degraded mode, chances are that all the drives are fine. You just need to rebuild the array, which is re-constructed from the super block info on each one of the drives. The data is almost certainly going to be fine. It's just part of system management to keep an eye on the status of your arrays.

I run a RAID 5 array using a bunch of 1TB drives in an external array. On my old system which was dated, and only had 1GB of memory (couldn't buy that type of memory any more) I had problems somewhat regularly. I replaced the system with a new one, bought 12GB of memory, moved the external array over and it works MUCH better.